# Rails: List of a nested items through a many-to-many relation model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, has-many-through, has-many

I am new to rails and there's something I don't fully understand.

I have 4 models as follows:

```
class Unit
  belongs_to :compound
  belongs_to :unit_type
end
```

```
class UnitType
  has_many :units
  has_many :unit_type_compounds
  has_many :compounds, through: :unit_type_compounds
end
```

```
class Compound
  has_many :units
  has_many :unit_type_compounds
  has_many :unit_types, through: :unit_type_compounds
end
```

```
class UnitTypeCompound
  belongs_to :unit_type
  belongs_to :compound
end
```

I want to get all `units` [with active status] through a `unit_type_compound`

I've tried the following but when I inspect the query I find it's wrong

first:

```
class UnitTypeCompound
  belongs_to :unit_type
  belongs_to :compound

  has_many :units, through: :unit_type
end
```

the query [for a single item `UnitTypeCompound.all.first.units`] was something like:

```
SELECT `units`.*
FROM `units`
  INNER JOIN `unit_types` ON `units`.`unit_type_id` = `unit_types`.`id`
WHERE `unit_types`.`id` = ?
  /* loading for inspect */
LIMIT 11
```

second:

```
class UnitTypeCompound
  belongs_to :unit_type
  belongs_to :compound
  has_many :units, through: :unit_type, source: :unit_type_compounds

  has_many :vacant_units, ->{ where(status: :vacant) }, class_name: Unit.to_s,
           through: :unit_type, source: :unit_type_compounds
end
```

the query [for a single item `UnitTypeCompound.all.first.units`] was something like:

```
SELECT `units`.*
FROM `units`
  /* Note: the following condition is units.id, not compounds.id */
  INNER JOIN `unit_type_compounds` ON `units`.`id` = `unit_type_compounds`.`compound_id`
  INNER JOIN `unit_types` ON `unit_type_compounds`.`unit_type_id` = `unit_types`.`id`
WHERE `unit_types`.`id` = ?
  /* loading for inspect */
LIMIT 11
```

and query [for a single item `UnitTypeCompound.all.first.vacant_units`] was something like:

```
SELECT `units`.*
FROM `units`
  /* Note: the same condition */
  INNER JOIN `unit_type_compounds` ON `units`.`id` = `unit_type_compounds`.`compound_id`
  INNER JOIN `unit_types` ON `unit_type_compounds`.`unit_type_id` = `unit_types`.`id`
WHERE `unit_types`.`id` = ?
  AND `units`.`status` = 0
  /* loading for inspect */
LIMIT 11
```

third:

It worked using the method

```
class UnitTypeCompound
  belongs_to :unit_type
  belongs_to :compound

  def vacant_units
    Unit.where(status: :vacant)
        .where(compound: compound)
        .where(unit_type: unit_type)
  end
end
```

and query [for a single item `UnitTypeCompound.all.first.vacant_units`] was something like:

```
SELECT `units`.*
FROM `units`
WHERE `units`.`sellable` = FALSE
    AND `units`.`compound_id` = ?
    AND `units`.`unit_type_id` = ?
    AND `units`.`status` = 0
    /* loading for inspect */
LIMIT 11
```

but, I wonder if there's a way through `has_many` or something?

Comment: can you share query for method which worked i.e third one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario is not suitable for `has_many` for a few reasons. You are in a situation where `UnitTypeCompound` has many `units` through two different associations and you want an intersection of `units` from these two associations.

First reason this should not work with `has_many` is that using natural language you would expect that if `UnitTypeCompound` has many units it would be a union of those two associations, not an intersection.

Second reason is that `has_many` should be reversible. If you call `unit.unit_type_compounds` would you expect it to be `unit.unit_type.unit_type_compounds`, `unit.compound.unit_type_compounds`, union of those two or their intersection?

Third is that you should be able to call `collection<<` method on the association. If you called `unit_type_compound.units << Unit.last` should it create that association through `UnitType` or `Compound`?

Your scenario has a lot of abibiguity that cannot be expressed by a simple `has_many :units, through:` therefore if the `vacant_units` method works for you, I would stick with it.

If you want to try to do it with an association, my best guess is that it should look like this:

```rb
class UnitTypeCompound
  belongs_to :unit_type
  belongs_to :compound

  has_many :vacant_units, ->(unit_type_compound){ where(compound_id: unit_type_compound.compound_id, status: :vacant) },
           through: :unit_type, source: :units 
end
```

Comment: I agree with you, I'm just wondering if there's any way through relations

Comment: @KhogaEslam updated the answer with a code